# How to get specific information in json with GSON in java

Tags: java, json, gson

I need some help reading .json files.

I have this file (information for the 3D animations models with CraftStudio):

```
{
  "title": "Idle",
  "duration": 120,
  "holdLastKeyframe": false,
  "nodeAnimations": {
    "Upper Arm Right": {
      "position": {
      },
      "offsetFromPivot": {
      },
      "size": {
      },
      "rotation": {
        "0": [ 0, 0, -4.171811 ],
        "30": [ 0, 0, -1.254342 ],
        "60": [ 0, 0, -6.620682 ],
        "90": [ 0, 0, -2.199501 ]
      },
      "stretch": {
      }
    },
    "Upper Arm Left": {
      "position": {
      },
      "offsetFromPivot": {
      },
      "size": {
      },
      "rotation": {
        "0": [ 0, 0, 7.722006 ],
        "30": [ 0, 0, 0.891409 ],
        "60": [ 0, 0, 7.101573 ],
        "90": [ 0, 0, 3.180463 ]
      },
      "stretch": {
      }
    },
    "Spine": {
      "position": {
      },
      "offsetFromPivot": {
      },
      "size": {
      },
      "rotation": {
        "0": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
        "60": [ 4.786639, 0, 0 ]
      },
      "stretch": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to know how I can get all parts ("Upper Arm Right" by example) in the "nodeAnimations" jsonobject. Maybe a list?

The problem is that I don't know the names of the parts that i am trying to get.

and it's the same for the keyframe (0, 30, 60, 90)

```
"rotation": {
        "0": [ 0, 0, -4.171811 ],
        "30": [ 0, 0, -1.254342 ],
        "60": [ 0, 0, -6.620682 ],
        "90": [ 0, 0, -2.199501 ]
      }
```

How I can get all of the information? It could have `90+` or `- keyframe` and the parts may be named differently.

It's in Java with GSON lib. Would an other json lib can be better for this?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gson and parse the model, then get the values using the keys...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String input = "{\"title\": \"Idle\", \"duration\": 120, \"holdLastKeyframe\": false, \"nodeAnimations\": {"
    + "\"Upper Arm Right\": { \"position\": { },\"offsetFromPivot\": {},\"size\": {},\"rotation\": {\"0\": [ 0, 0, -4.171811 ],\"30\": [ 0, 0, -1.254342 ],\"60\": [ 0, 0, -6.620682 ],\"90\": [ 0, 0, -2.199501 ]},\"stretch\": {}},\"Upper Arm Left\": {\"position\": {},\"offsetFromPivot\": {},\"size\": {},\"rotation\": {\"0\": [ 0, 0, 7.722006 ],\"30\": [ 0, 0, 0.891409 ],\"60\": [ 0, 0, 7.101573 ],\"90\": [ 0, 0, 3.180463 ]},\"stretch\": {}},\"Spine\": {\"position\": {},\"offsetFromPivot\": {},\"size\": {},\"rotation\": {\"0\": [ 0, 0, 0 ],\"60\": [ 4.786639, 0, 0 ]},\"stretch\": {}}}}";
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(input, JsonObject.class);
System.out.println(jsonObject);
System.out.println("Upper Arm Right:" + jsonObject.get("nodeAnimations").getAsJsonObject()
    .get("Upper Arm Right").getAsJsonObject().get("rotation"));
System.out.println("Upper Arm Left:" + jsonObject.get("nodeAnimations").getAsJsonObject().get("Upper Arm Left")
    .getAsJsonObject().get("rotation"));
System.out.println("Spine:"
    + jsonObject.get("nodeAnimations").getAsJsonObject().get("Spine").getAsJsonObject().get("rotation"));
}
```

## Edit:

you maybe need the values in some iterative way...

then what you can do is get from the json element the entry set and then get the **rotation** object

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String input = "{\"title\": \"Idle\", \"duration\": 120, \"holdLastKeyframe\": false, \"nodeAnimations\": {"
    + "\"Upper Arm Right\": { \"position\": { },\"offsetFromPivot\": {},\"size\": {},\"rotation\": {\"0\": [ 0, 0, -4.171811 ],\"30\": [ 0, 0, -1.254342 ],\"60\": [ 0, 0, -6.620682 ],\"90\": [ 0, 0, -2.199501 ]},\"stretch\": {}},\"Upper Arm Left\": {\"position\": {},\"offsetFromPivot\": {},\"size\": {},\"rotation\": {\"0\": [ 0, 0, 7.722006 ],\"30\": [ 0, 0, 0.891409 ],\"60\": [ 0, 0, 7.101573 ],\"90\": [ 0, 0, 3.180463 ]},\"stretch\": {}},\"Spine\": {\"position\": {},\"offsetFromPivot\": {},\"size\": {},\"rotation\": {\"0\": [ 0, 0, 0 ],\"60\": [ 4.786639, 0, 0 ]},\"stretch\": {}}}}";
JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(input, JsonObject.class);
for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entrySet : jsonObject.get("nodeAnimations").getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entrySet.getKey());
    System.out.println(entrySet.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("rotation"));
}
}
```

Comment: Yes it's a solution but here you get directly the part name with .get("Upper Arm Right") but I want to get it without knowing its name, and this is my problem 'cause here it's "Upper Arm Right" but it could be "Bla Bla Part"

Comment: ok @ZeAmateis would you prefer like in an iteration, for loop or similar...??